# fingerprint scannaner

Tags: java, c++, c, vb.net

I have code to scan a fingerprint template from digitalpersona device . It work's for me. But it also has some more feature's, like storing templates, verification etc. I just want to extract the command or code to just scan fingerprint template from device. I have the code in 4 different language's(vb,java,c++,c).Can any 1 help me?

Comment: No. This question is far too broad for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: No idea if we can help. Perhaps give some more information about _which_ device first off...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The code supplied to you is owned by DigitalPersona and written in C++. It is closed source. Unfortunately you will have to reverse engineer it to abstract only a few features out of it.

If you notice, all the other code written call the native C++ dll functions to do their "dirty" work.

No source code of the DLL is supplied to you. Hence, you cannot just copy-paste *some* code out of DP's finger-print hardware interaction code.

Comment: Source: I tried to mess around and reverse engineer this stuff too.

Comment: now there is no way to scan a fingerprint template from digital persona device? By developing my own code.......

Comment: DigitalPersona? I think you can use libfprint: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/Supported_devices/